# undefined reference to WinMain@16 when using boost with MinGW

Tags: c++, boost, makefile, mingw, eclipse-cdt

I'm programming in C++ with Eclipse under Windows 7.

My makefile is as follows:

```
build:
    g++ -shared -o "lib\libCacheOpt.a" "src\*.cpp" -enable-auto-import -I"${CWD}\include" -I"${BOOST}" -L"${BOOST}\lib" -lboost_program_options -lboost_unit_test_framework

exec: build
    g++ "src\main.cpp" -enable-auto-import -I"${CWD}\include" -L"${CWD}\lib" -I"${BOOST}" -L"${BOOST}\lib" -lCacheOpt -lboost_program_options -o Simulator.exe

test: build
    g++ "test\unit\*.cpp" -enable-auto-import -I"${CWD}\include" -L"${CWD}\lib" -I"${BOOST}" -L"${BOOST}\lib" -lmingw32 -lCacheOpt -lboost_unit_test_framework -o run_tests.exe

clean:
    rm Simulator.exe
    rm "lib\libCacheOpt.a"
```

When I do `make build` or `make exec` everything works fine. However, when using `make test` I get `undefined reference to 'WinMain@16'`. The only file under `test/` is this one, using boost's unit test framework:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE ChunkTest
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

#include <Chunk.h>
using namespace CacheOpt;

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( getChunks )
{
    Chunk::setSize(10);
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(Chunk::getSize(), 11);
}
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you don't have a `main` method. You can create one using `BOOST_TEST_MAIN`. `BOOST_TEST_MODULE` only defines `main` if and only if `BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK` is already defined.